# What would happen to a spinning gyroscope drifting through space?

Tags: gyroscopes

Imagine we set a gyroscope spinning and pointed in a certain direction and then set it adrift in space.  The gyroscope drifts through space for billions of years and eventually it drifts back to us.  Assume it stays spinning without losing any rotational energy.  Would the gyroscope still be pointed in the original direction?  Or would gravity, warped space, or whatever cause it to change orientation?

Comment: The spin axis of the earth changes direction slowly. That's a huge gyro. Why should yours be any different?

Comment: How about polarized photons?